# UIDocumentInteractionController Disable Options Menu

Tags: ios, pdf, uidocumentinteraction

I have a PDF showing in a `UIDocumentInteractionController` and its great.

Problem is, the point of the app is to protect the PDF from being shared etc. Hence I want to get rid of the options button that appears.

There are 1000 similar Q's on stack, but before you go linking me to what I have already read please keep in mind that I need an iOS6 solution.

I have tried implementing the willShowMenu related functions, and a bunch of other stuff.

End of the day, this needs to get onto the store, and we all know how rigid apple are, so if anyone has a solid store-aproved ios6 solution that would be great.

If not, could anyone point me in the right direction and I will work it out. Is there an alternative to UIDocumentInteractionController for display (but copy protecting) PDFs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView to display PDF file.

To disable copy menu, Add the following code in the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate of UIWebView

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitUserSelect='none';"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout='none';"]
```